# Is 'clearing' an object a viable way to avoid using hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, object, hasownproperty

I understand why hasOwnProperty is necessary even when one has complete control over an object, since Object.prototype may have been modified.  But if I really want to avoid it, consider this:

```
function CleanObject() {
    var result = {};
    for (var key in result) {
        delete result[key];
    }
    return result;
}

// Later...

var obj = CleanObject();
for (var key in obj) {
    // No hasOwnProperty check necessary
}
```

In other words I'm clearing the instance of properties before using it.  Should this work, or am I missing some edge-case?

Comment: http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.7 states: `delete`s do not propagate up the prototype chain (although not as clearly).

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a "Clean" object that has no properties using the `Object.create()` syntax passing in `null` as a param.

Example:

```
var clean = Object.create(null);

for(var key in clean) {
 //do stuff no hasOwnProperties required
}
```

Comment: Seems like a valid solution to the problem to me, thanks